# Can't connect slaves to master in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, google-compute-engine

Using 4 instances on Compute Engine, each running spark set up with Cloudera Manager. I have no problems starting the master and connecting in my local browser, and it connects as spark://instance-1:7077. When I start the start-slave on the remaining instances I get no errors, until I look in the log:

```
16/05/02 13:10:18 INFO worker.Worker: Started daemon with process name: 12612@instance-2.c.cluster1-1294.internal
16/05/02 13:10:18 INFO worker.Worker: Registered signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
16/05/02 13:10:18 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
16/05/02 13:10:18 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
16/05/02 13:10:18 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(root); users with mod$
16/05/02 13:10:19 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 60270.
16/05/02 13:10:19 INFO worker.Worker: Starting Spark worker 10.142.0.3:60270 with 2 cores, 6.3 GB RAM
16/05/02 13:10:19 INFO worker.Worker: Running Spark version 1.6.0
16/05/02 13:10:19 INFO worker.Worker: Spark home: /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark
16/05/02 13:10:19 ERROR worker.Worker: Failed to create work directory /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark/work
```

If i use mkdir to create 'work' then it throws and error and says the directory already exists:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘work’: File exists
```

The file does exist and when using ls to find it it is highlighted in red with a black background. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the permission issue,

Try this,

```
   $sudo chown -R your_userName:your_groupName /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark
```

Now change the Mode of the above path

```
  $sudo chmod 777 /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark
```

Also all the slaves must have ssh to each other and can able to talk one another.

And Copy all the Configuration file of spark to the slave nodes also.